# Access violation on try to fill dynamic array (large number of items)

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, malloc, dynamic-memory-allocation

I have the following C code:

```
int dimension; 
double *AtS;
...
AtS=(double*)malloc(sizeof(double)*dimension); 

for (i=0; i<dimension; i++)
{
  AtS[i]=0.0; 
}
```

While `dimension` is ~6-8 millions it works fine, but when it about 300 millions it fails with access violation. The following message in debug:

> Unhandled exception at 0x012f1077 in mathpro.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation writing location 0x00000000.

The same situation if I use `memset()` instead of cycle.

Are there any ideas how it's resolve this problem?

Comment: Did you check `malloc` succeeded? `300 millions` is a lot.

Comment: Seems to me that `malloc` failed and you're access memory pages that you do not own. Error sounds legit.

Comment: 300,000,000 * 8 (bytes per double) is 2.29 **gigabytes** of requested *contiguous* allocation. Unless your running a x64 process (and judging by those reported addresses in your posted messaging, you're not), that stands near-no-chance of being fulfilled. Blessed is the pessimist, for they are the ones that check their function return results rather than assuming they worked. Assumption is the mother of all....

Comment: I assume you're compiling a 32 bits executable? If yes, that's probably because you are going beyond the address space that you can address with 32 bits. You can try compiling in 64bits to see if it helps.

Comment: This is why you *always* check the result of `malloc`.

Comment: Yes, it works on x64.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"Access violation writing location 0x00000000" is explained by the manual

http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/malloc.3.html#RETURN_VALUE

> On error, these functions return NULL.

Or if you prefer http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdlib/malloc/.

> ### Return Value
>
> On success, a pointer to the memory block allocated by
> the function. The type of this pointer is always void*, which can be
> cast to the desired type of data pointer in order to be
> dereferenceable. **If the function failed to allocate the requested
> block of memory, a null pointer is returned.**

You have encountered an error. Quite likely out of memory.

If you were to inspect the value `sizeof(double)*dimension` prior to passing it to malloc, you'll find that it is indeed quite a large number.

Answer (score 2):

As already explained by Mr. [Captain Giraffe](https://stackoverflow.com/users/451600/captain-giraffe) in the [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30849664/2173917) that you're facing the issue because the memory allocation through `malloc()` has failed (quite likely for *very large* allocation request) and you did not check for the success of `malloc()` before using the returned pointer.

In case of failure. `malloc()` will return `NULL` and without a check, you'll be dereferencing a `NULL` pointer, which in turn invokes [undefined behaviour](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).

Along with that, I would like to add three more points, e.g.,

1. Please [do not cast](https://stackoverflow.com/q/605845/2173917) the return value of `malloc()` and family in `C`.
2. You need not use a `loop` to initialize the (properly) allocated memory to `0`. Rather, to get this done in an efficient manner, use either

   - you can use [`calloc()`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/calloc), which returns the 
     memory set to zero.
   - you can use `malloc()` and then [`memset()`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/memset) to set the allocated memory to the particular value supplied with `memset()`.
3. The *robust* way to use `malloc()` in an expression is to write the expression as

   ```
   AtS=malloc(dimension * sizeof*AtS);   //sizeof is an operator
   ```

   which is independent to the *type* of `AtS`. At a later point, if the type of `AtS` is changed, you don't need to modify this expression at all.